# Reading double data from file and print with a function

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to have a function to which I can pass a 2D array of any size, and it will be printed - sounds simple. This should be helpful to check if my math is correct, as I'm building engineering models.

In the code shown, I first read in the data from a text file, and it is stored in a 4x6 double array, called 'data'. Then I print the array from main() by iterating through each element and printing it out, which works fine. To test if the function is working, I introduced 'data_test', another 4x6 array which has some values assigned to it. When I pass 'data_test' to the function, it works as desired. But it does NOT work when I pass 'data', the data read from a file - I get a compiler error saying "no matching function for call to ‘print2d_double(double [Nrow][Ncol])’"

What is going on here? Why will it compile when I pass an array with values that I assign manually, but it won't compile if I try to pass an array that is read in from a file? Is something wrong with the way I have read in the values from the file?

I'm pretty new to c++. Thanks for any ideas!
The text file reads like this:

1 1 0 0 0 100

2 1 0.01 0 0 200

3 1 0 0.01 0 300

4 1 0 0 0.01 400

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

// This prints a 2D array of doubles with any dimensions
template <size_t size_x, size_t size_y>
void print2d_double(double (&arr)[size_x][size_y])
{
    int counter = 0;
    int Nrow = size_x;
    int Ncol = size_y;
    for (int row=0;row<Nrow;row++){
        for (int col=0;col<Ncol;col++){
            printf("%f",arr[row][col]);
            counter++;
            if (counter % (Ncol) == 0)
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf(", ");
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int Nrow = 4; // number of rows to read in
    int Ncol = 6; // number of columns to read in
    double data[Nrow][Ncol]; // initialize array

    //Read data from the file
    ifstream file("fill_1_short.txt");
    if(file.is_open())
    {
        for (int row = 0; row<Nrow; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < Ncol; col++)
            {
                file >> data[row][col];
            }
        }
    }
    else {printf("I'm closed - did not open file.\n");}

    //Printing 'data' directly in main() works
    printf("Printing 'data' from main():\n");
    int counter=0;
    for (int row=0;row<Nrow;row++){
        for (int col=0;col<Ncol;col++){
            printf("%f",data[row][col]);
            counter++;
            if (counter % (Ncol) == 0)
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf(", ");
            }
        }
    }

    // Passing an array to the function also works, if the values of the array
    // are set directly:
    printf("Printing 'data_test' to test the function:\n");
    double data_test[4][6] = { {1,1,1,1,1,1},{2,2,2,2,2,2},{1,1,1,1,1,1},   {2,2,2,2,2,2} };
    print2d_double(data_test);

    // But passing the array 'data' that was read in does not work:
    printf("Printing 'data' with function:\n");
    print2d_double(data);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Always** check *after* reading that your attempt to read data was successful, e.g.: `if (file >> data[row][col]) { ... }`

Comment: C++ does not support variable length built-in arrays. Your problem is that you are specifying your array with run-time values and try to deduce the size via a template. Templates are inherently compile-time. Declare your dimensions as constant expressions (e.g., using `constexpr int Nrow = 4;`) to fix that problem.

Comment: I was just posting that as an answer and did not see your question. Sorry.

Comment: It would be very nice of you @e_johnson if you either upvote or accept some of the answers.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses! All of these answers and comments provided were very helpful, and I have marked them as such. With a quick addition to make them constant values as indicated, it runs fine. This is an important detail I hadn't yet come across in learning c++. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`double data[Nrow][Ncol];` is not conformant C++. As `Nrow` and `Ncol` are not explicitely declared `constexpr`, `data` is a Variable Length Array for which the dimensions are know only at run time. This is an optional feature in C11 (**not C++** whatever version) that is accepted by some C++ compilers, like gcc.

This is enough:

```
constexpr int Nrow = 4; // number of rows to read in
constexpr int Ncol = 6; // number of columns to read in
```

to get read of the compilation error, and have correct C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the compiler cannot deduce the size of `data`. This is because you allocate it with nonconstant values. If you declare your `Nrow` and `Ncol` as constant then it compiles:

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    const int Nrow(4); // number of rows to read in
    const int Ncol(6); // number of columns to read in
    double data[Nrow][Ncol]; // initialize array
    ...
 }
```

In this way, the compiler knows at compile time what size will data be.